# How to get the height of renderItem from FlatList?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My goal is to get the height of a `<View></View>` used by `renderItem` function for the `<FlatList />` component, and use it for the `<Image />` component inside the `renderItem`

```
const renderItem = () => {
  let height;

  return
    <View onLayout={event => {height = event.nativeElement.layout.height}}>
      <Image style={{width: height}]/> // I wish to use it like this.
    </View>
}
```

The height does change but unfortunately, it does not re-render. I also tried to use the `re-render` pattern with `React.useState()`, unfortunately, `renderItem` function is not a React function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
height = event.nativeElement.layout.height
```

This statement will never trigger a re-render of your function, and you will pass **undefined** to your width style. The solution is to create a new component **CustomizedView** that will manage the **state** **height** like this:

```
export default function CustomizedView() {
  const [heightState, setHeightState] = useState();
  return (
    <View
      onLayout={(event) => {
        setHeightState(event.nativeElement.layout.height);
      }}
    >
      <Image style={{ width: heightState }} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: You might create array state with length as the `FlatList` data length, as in your solution all items gonna write on the same place

Comment: Doesn't this will cause re-render for each item?

Comment: Yes it will re-render for each item, I think the best solution is to create a new component,
with this jsx :
   <View onLayout={event => {setHeightState(event.nativeElement.layout.height)}}>
      <Image style={{width: heightState}]/> // I wish to use it like this.
    </View>, and add your state.

Comment: @HagaiHarari, I agree with you, we need to create array state.

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil Yep, could you please edit your answer and suggest to create a new component, to avoid re-render the entire component. Anyway, I am not sure it's recommended (as I couldn't find it on the official docs, although it is do able), if you may, could you look it for me about the performance impact of using separate component?. I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @kidfrom Using separate component is a good approach, you can check the official doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html. I will be happy if you can check the answer :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use local state to store the `height` value.
As metioned `renderItem` is not a react function just pass the `height` state value and its setter function as props from Parent component of `renderItem()`. So when this `height` state value changes it will re-render the component.

```
const renderItem = (height,setHeight) => {
  return
    <View onLayout={event => setHeight(event.nativeElement.layout.height)}>
      <Image style={{width: height}}/>
    </View>
}
```

and from parent component where `renderItem` is called

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
 const [height,setHeight] = useState();
 ...
 ...
 renderItem(height,setHeight)
}
```